# Django tastypie filter boolean field

Tags: django, boolean, filtering, tastypie

I have class in models.py:

```
class Companies(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=1, editable=False)
```

In HTML template have this radiogroup:

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Status</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="is_active" value="">All</label>
    <input type="radio" name="is_active" value="True" checked="1">Active</label>
    <input type="radio" name="is_active" value="False">Not Active</label>
   </fieldset>
```

using jquery i want to serialize() radiogroup and send to tastypie API to get filtered data from model:

URL from query then will look like this:

`http://localhost:8000/api/view/company/list/?is_active=`

result will show only rows with **False** values in is_active field

if i use **?is_active=1** results will be only **True**

How can i get both **True and False** rows from table?

i can change "name" attr in input, but name must be the same in all inputs to stay grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `?is_active=` on the Django side the request will have 'is_active' in POST dictionary:

```
>>> 'is_active' in request.POST`
True
```

The problem is the content is string which is empty here:

```
>>> request.POST['is_active']
'' # Or None I am not quite sure.
```

And according to Python semantic:

```
>>> bool(None)
False
>>> bool(False)
False
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool('')
False
```

All negative values are: `[]`, `()`, `{}`, `set()`, `0`, `''`, `None`, `False`

You have to override `build_filters` to remove this key if its empty or don't call API with that value being empty.

```
def build_filters(self, filters=None):
    if filters is None:
        filters = {}

    if "is_active" in filters and filters["is_active"] == '': # or == None you have to check
        del filters['is_active']

    return super(MyResource, self).build_filters(filters)
```